# PHP 5.2.6 executes very slow on IIS 6

Tags: php, performance

I just recently upgraded from PHP 5.2.1 to 5.3.5.  Had problems with my joomla sites, so I downgraded to 5.2.6, but now all my sites are running super slow.  What could be the cause of this in the php ini file?

Comment: Well it could be one of the settings, which we are however unable to debug since you didn't show your php.ini or phpinfo comparisons between your php5.3 and 5.2 setup.

Answer (score 2):

With PHP 5.2.x you'll never get anywhere near the performance of PHP 5.3 on IIS.. especially on IIS 6. If at all possible, upgrade to IIS7 as soon as possible. I *think* you can do it for free through the Web Platform Installer (WebPI).

Also, what version of Joomla are you using? I'm pretty sure 1.5 was 5.3-compatible. More importantly, Joomla 1.6 was released last week so you may check out upgrading that too.

Here's some history of the situation:
http://www.slideshare.net/ruslany/php-performance-on-windows

**Disclosure:** *Those slides are from a webcast I hosted with php|architect last year and I've worked with Microsoft and PHP on IIS and getting my Open Source project into WebPI.*